# PHP snippet always shows in the top of page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently using a database search in wordpress wherein I show the results in the result page via snippets.
The problem is the results always get displayed in the top of page. I do understand php executes first before html, but is there a way to get the results displayed where I want?

**Code:**

```
Wordpress: [xyz-ips snippet="industry"]
```

**Php:**

```
$com=$_GET['company'];
$sql2 = "SELECT count(1) i from data where sector= (SELECT sector from data where company like '$com%')";
$rows2 = $wpdb->get_results($sql2 );
echo ' '.$rows2[0]->i.' ';
```

Comment: with out code, not even Buddha could help you

Comment: I'm sorry nogad, but its the usual php DB search code. Attached below:

PHP: 
$com=$_GET['company'];
$sql2 = "SELECT count(1) i from data where sector= (SELECT sector from data where company like '$com%')";
$rows2 = $wpdb->get_results($sql2 );
echo ' '.$rows2[0]->i.' ';

results page:
[xyz-ips snippet="industry"]

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you need to find where in WordPress the *string* of HTML is being output.

Then, you move it to where you want the HTML to be output.

The general idea, as you said, is that PHP executes (echo $html) before your browser reads the HTML sent by PHP. Your PHP script will run in order, top to bottom, so by moving sections of PHP that output HTML (or anything) to a different part of your script, you change its location on the page.

It's hard to give further input without understanding your situation in detail. I would highly recommend browsing the documentation for your "WordPress search" to see if there is a best practice for accomplishing what you want.

Comment: As said, I'm using a snippet. So, I tried moving it and also putting in separate <div>. But, it doesn't work.!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the intelligent community here, they are more curious to downvote than to help fellow mate.!
I discovered after much search that the php version caused this. I downgraded (from the current 5.6) to 5.5 and that solved the issue.
This might help someone who is searching for a similar answer.